# Subfield subcodes of Reed-Solomon Codes

Tags: coding-theory

Notation: Let ${\mathbb F}=GF(q)$ for some prime $q$, and $K=GF(q^n)$ for some $n>1$. Let $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_{N}$ be distinct nonzero elements of $K$, where $N\leq q^n-1$. (I am leaving $N$ and the $\{\alpha_i\}$ arbitrary, but if it helps in answering any of the questions below then feel free to take them of some special form.)

I am trying to understand better subfield subcodes of Reed-Solomon codes. A Reed-Solomon code of dimension $k$ is given by $\mathcal{C}_{RS} = \{(p(\alpha_1), \ldots, p(\alpha_N)) \mid \mbox{$p \in K[X]$ of degree $k-1$}\}$. We define the subfield subcode of $\mathcal{C}$ as $\mathcal{C}' = \mathcal{C}_{RS} \cap {\mathbb F}^N$.

Question 1: We equivalently have $\mathcal{C}' = \{(p(\alpha_1), \ldots, p(\alpha_N)) \mid \mbox{$p\in K[X]$ of degree $k-1$ with $p(\alpha_1), \ldots, p(\alpha_N) \in {\mathbb F}$}\}$. Is there is simple characterization of the polynomials $p\in K[X]$ of degree $k-1$ for which $p(\alpha_1), \ldots, p(\alpha_N) \in {\mathbb F}$?

Question 2: Say $\mathcal{C}'$ has dimension $k'$. If I want to view $\mathcal{C}'$ as a systematic code, under what conditions will it hold that for any $v \in {\mathbb F}^{k'}$ there is a codeword $c \in \mathcal{C}'$ whose first $k'$ coordinates are equal to $v$?

Comment: Regrettably, the definition that you use of BCH codes does not match any of the standard definitions of BCH codes.

Comment: It is used [here](https://cse.buffalo.edu/faculty/atri/courses/coding-theory/book) (Exercise 5.10) as well as [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvjLPJFAUOw). I certainly didn't make it up myself! In any event, isn't the statement correct (whether or not you take that as the definition of a BCH code)?

Comment: That nonstandard definition of BCH code is I believe used in the Theoretical Computer Science community. In standard coding theory BCH codes are not evaluation codes.

Comment: So is there no relation between the "standard" definition of BCH codes and the one I gave? In any event, I will rephrase my question to eliminate the offending terminology.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is for the special case when $F = \mathbb F_q$,$K = \mathbb F_{q^n}$, $N = q^n-1$ and $(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \ldots, \alpha_N) = (\beta^0, \beta^1, \ldots, \beta^{N-1})$ where $\beta$ is a a primitive element of $K$.  Thus, the codewords of what the OP calls $C_{RS}$ are vectors over ${K}$ of the form
$$\big(\, P_0, P_1, \cdots, P_{N-1}\,\big) = \big (\, p(1), p(\beta), \cdots, p(\beta^{N-1})\, \big )\tag{1}$$ where $p(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} p_ix^i$ of a polynomial of degree smaller than $k$ in $K[x]$.  Now, if $\alpha=\beta^{-1}$, we can write
$$\big (\, p(1), p(\beta), \cdots, p(\beta^{N-1})\, \big )= \big (\, p(1), p(\alpha^{-1}), \cdots, p(\alpha^{-(N-1)})\, \big )$$
and view the codeword $\big(\, P_0, P_1, \cdots, P_{N-1}\,\big)$ of $C_{RS}$ as the Galois field Fourier transform of $\big(\,p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_{k-1}, 0, 0, \ldots, 0\,\big)$. We associate the polynomial
$P(z) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1}P_iz^i$ with the codeword $\big(\, P_0, P_1, \cdots, P_{N-1}\,\big).$
Now, the inverse Fourier transform of $\big(\, P_0, P_1, \cdots, P_{N-1}\,\big)$ is  $\frac 1N \big (\, P(1), P(\alpha), \cdots, P(\alpha^{N-1})\, \big )$ which gives us back $\big( \, p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_{k-1}, 0, 0, \ldots, 0\,\big)$.  Here, $\frac 1N$ is the multiplicative inverse of $N = q^n-1$ and so equals $-1$ in this case.  Hence, we have that
$$- P(\alpha^m) = -\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}P_j\alpha^{mj}
= \begin{cases} p_m & 0 \leq m \leq k-1,\\
0, & k \leq m \leq N-1.\end{cases}$$
Note that $P(\alpha^m) = P(\beta^{-m}) = 0$ for $k \leq m \leq N-1$
showing that $P(z)$ has $\beta, \beta^2, \ldots, \beta^{N-k}$ as roots, that is, $P(z)$ is a multiple of $g(z)$  where
$$g(z) = \prod_{i=1}^{N-k} (z-\beta^i).\tag{2}$$

> Henceforth, we take the codewords of $C_{RS}$ to be the $(q^n)^k$ polynomials in $K[z]$ of degree smaller than $N$ that are multiples of $g(z)$ of degree $N-k$ as defined in $(2)$.
> These codewords constitute a *cyclic* $[N,k] =[q^n-1,k]$ Reed-Solomon code over ${K} = \mathbb F_{q^n}$.

All the codewords of $C_{RS}$ are polynomials over ${K}= \mathbb F_{q^n}$. How many (if any) of the codewords of $C_{RS}$ are polynomials over ${F} = \mathbb F_{q}$? Well, a little thought shows that these *subfield* vectors also comprise a *cyclic* code (but over $F$, not over ${K}$). Call this code $C_{BCH}$ (because it is indeed a (primitive, narrow-sense) BCH code over $F$ according to the definition of BCH code that coding theorists generally use but Theoretical Computer Scientists don't), and let $\hat{g}(z)$ denote its generator polynomial. Since every codeword in $C_{RS}$ is a multiple of $g(z)$, so is every codeword in $C_{BCH}$ a multiple of $g(z)$, and so it must be that $g(z)$ is a divisor of $\hat{g}(z)$. We know that $g(z)$ has $N-k$ roots and all of these must be roots of $\hat{g}(z)$ also. But, since $\hat{g}(z) \in {F}[z]$, *all the conjugates* of the roots of $g(z)$ also are roots of $\hat{g}(z)$.  Thus, it must be that
$g(z) \mid \hat{g}(z)$ and $\deg \hat{g}(z) > \deg g(z)$. In some cases, it might be that $C_{BCH}$ is a $[N,1]$ repetition code.

Example: Take $q=2, n=4, N=15, k=13$. Then, $g(z)$ has roots $\beta, \beta^2$ (which happen to be conjugates) while $\hat{g}(z)$ also has as roots $\beta^4$ and $\beta^8$ (the other two conjugate of $\beta$ and $\beta^2$).  Thus, $C_{RS}$ is a cyclic  $[15,13]$ Reed-Solomon code over $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ while $C_{BCH}$ is a $[15,11]$ single-error correcting BCH code (in fact a Hamming code) code over $\mathbb F_2$. But if $k=11$, then $C_{RS}$ is a cyclic  $[15,11]$ Reed-Solomon code over $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ while $C_{BCH}$ is a $[15,7]$ double-error-correcting BCH code over $\mathbb F_2$. Next, if $k=9$, then $C_{RS}$ is a cyclic  $[15,9]$ Reed-Solomon code over $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ while $C_{BCH}$ is a $[15,5]$ triple-error-correcting BCH code over $\mathbb F_2$. Finally, if  $k=7$, then $C_{RS}$ is a cyclic  $[15,7]$ quadruple-error-correcting Reed-Solomon code over $\mathbb{F}_{2^4}$ while $C_{BCH}$ is the $[15,1]$ seven-error-correcting BCH code (in fact a *repetition code*) over $\mathbb F_2$.

Next, to answer the OP's Question 1, we need to consider the codewords $P(z)$ of $C_{RS}$  such that all the $P_i$ are in $F$, that is, $P(z) \in C_{BCH}$.
The litmus test for determining whether an element $\gamma \in \mathbb F_{q^n}$ belongs to its subfield $\mathbb F_q$ is to test whether $\gamma^q$ equals $\gamma$: $\gamma \in \mathbb F_q$ iff $\gamma^q=\gamma$. We are considering only those $P(z)$ such that all the $P_i$ satisfy $P_i^q = P_i$. Now,
\begin{align} (p_i)^q &= \left[(-1)P(\alpha^i)\right]^q\\
&= \left[(-1)\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} P_i\alpha^{ij}\right]^q\\
&= (-1)^q\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}  P_i^q\gamma^{qij}\\
&= -\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} P_i\gamma^{qji} \\
&= -P(\alpha^{qi})\\
&= p_{qi}\end{align}
Thus, the inverse Fourier transform $p(x)$ of $P(z) \in C_{BCH}$ must satisfy the *conjugacy* property:
$$\text{For each}~i, 0 \leq i < N, p_{qi}
= p_{qi \bmod N} = p_i^q. \tag{3}$$
In particular, since $P(\alpha^m) = 0$ for $k \leq m \leq N-1$,   it must be that some of the $p_i, 0 \leq i \leq k-1$ have value $0$. Those $p_i$ that are not zero must satisfy the vomjugayc constraint $(3)$.

For example, take $q=2, n=4, N=15, k=13$. Then, $g(z)$ has two roots $\alpha^{13}$ and $\alpha^{14}$ while $\hat{g}(z)$ as roots $\alpha^{11}$ and $\alpha^7$ also. Thus, in
$\big(p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_{12}, p_{13}, p_{14}\big)$ we must have $$p_{14}= p_{13} = p_{11} = p_7 = 0.$$
The remaining $p_i$ need not be $0$ but must satisfy $(3)$.
Thus,
$$p_2 = p_1^2,\quad p_4 = p_2^2 = p_1^4, \quad p_8 = p_4^2 = p_1^8.$$
$$p_6 = p_{3}^2, \quad p_{12} =p_{6}^2 =p_3^4, \quad p_{24 \bmod 15} = p_9 = p_{12}^2 = p_3^8.$$
$$p_{10}=p_{5}^2.$$
$$p_0 = p_0^2 \implies p_0 \in \mathbb F_2.$$

Finally, to answer Question 2 of the OP, in a cyclic code of dimension $k^\prime$, *any* $k^\prime$ consecutive symbols can be take to be the information symbols, and so

> Yes, for the set-up described in this answer, the first $k^\prime$ symbols of $C_{BCH}$ can be taken to be the information symbols *with no additional conditions whatsoever needing to be imposed*.

Comment: This is all true, however it doesn’t seem to answer either of the original questions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer to question 2. Any suggestions for question 1?